# Set ``autoincrement`` value based on dialects in Sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

I would like to control the value for the Column's argument `autoincrement` to be False for some dialects and True for others with Sqlalchemy.

```
Class Table(Base):
  Id = Column(Integer, autoincrement=False, primary_key=True)
```

In this case I am using my model against SqlServer and DuckDB.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle* you can do this by customising the compilation of the [CreateColumn](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/ddl.html#sqlalchemy.schema.CreateColumn) construct. I don't have access to MSSQL or DuckDB, so this example uses MySQL, but the approach would be the same regardless of dialect.

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateColumn


# Specify the dialect(s) that require the behaviour in the 
# decorator's arguments. You can create multiple decorated functions if 
# necessary, for example one for each dialect that deviates from standard
# behaviour.
@compiles(CreateColumn, 'mysql')
def my_column(element, compiler, **kw):
    column = element.element
    column.autoincrement = True
    return compiler.visit_create_column(element, **kw)


tbl = sa.Table('foos', sa.MetaData(), sa.Column('id', sa.Integer, primary_key=True))


def my_dump(sql, *multiparams, **params):
    print(sql.compile(dialect=engine.dialect))


engine = sa.create_mock_engine('mysql://', my_dump)
tbl.create(engine)
```

The script generates this output:

```sql
CREATE TABLE foos (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

---

* I'm assuming that setting the "right" value of the flag does what you want for each dialect, and you only want a way to condition the value of the flag based on the dialect in use.

Comment: Fantastic!  I didn't realise I can change the attributes on the column in these hooks and assumed they are only for controlling the generated sql! TYVM